# Hook to log results of calls to drupal_mail() made by other modules?

Tags: 7, emails

How can I get the success/failure response of [drupal_mail](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!mail.inc/function/drupal_mail/7)() generated by another modules?

[hook_mail_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_mail_alter/7)() doesn't return success/fail and [drupal_mail](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!mail.inc/function/drupal_mail/7)() is only helpful if the message is coming from my module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I can see is implementing [hook_watchdog()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_watchdog/7), and look for a error message that matches "Error sending e-mail (from %from to %to)."

```
function mymodule_watchdog(array $log_entry) {
  if ($log_entry['message'] == 'Error sending e-mail (from %from to %to)') {
    // ...  
  }
}
```

The alternative would be implementing a class that replaces `DefaultMailSystem`, which is a class implementing [MailSystemInterface](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!mail.inc/interface/MailSystemInterface/7). To achieve this, it is enough to change the value of the mail_system Drupal variable.

Comment: For a nice example of how to implement a [`MailSystemInterface`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21mail.inc/interface/MailSystemInterface/7). Take a look at the [maillog](http://drupal.org/project/maillog) module.